# Parsing json output for hive

Tags: json, parsing, limesurvey

I need to automatically move new cases (TheHive-Project) to LimeSurvey every 5 minutes. I have figured out the basis of the API script to add responses to LimeSurvey. However, I can't figure out how to add only new cases, and how to parse the Hive case data for the information I want to add.

So far I've been using curl to get a list of cases from hive. The following is the command and the output.

```
curl -su user:pass http://myhiveIPaddress:9000/api/case
```

> [{"createdBy":"charlie","owner":"charlie","createdAt":1498749369897,"startDate":1498749300000,"title":"test","caseId":1,"user":"charlie","status":"Open","description":"testtest","tlp":2,"tags":[],"flag":false,"severity":1,"metrics":{"Time for Alert to Handler Pickup":2,"Time from open to close":4,"Time from compromise to discovery":6},"updatedBy":"charlie","updatedAt":1498751817577,"id":"AVz0bH7yqaVU6WeZlx3w","_type":"case"},{"createdBy":"charlie","owner":"charlie","title":"testtest","caseId":3,"description":"ddd","user":"charlie","status":"Open","createdAt":1499446483328,"startDate":1499446440000,"severity":2,"tlp":2,"tags":[],"flag":false,"id":"AV0d-Z0DqHSVxnJ8z_HI","_type":"case"},{"createdBy":"charlie","owner":"charlie","createdAt":1499268177619,"title":"test test","user":"charlie","status":"Open","caseId":2,"startDate":1499268120000,"tlp":2,"tags":[],"flag":false,"description":"s","severity":1,"metrics":{"Time from open to close":2,"Time for Alert to Handler Pickup":3,"Time from compromise to discovery":null},"updatedBy":"charlie","updatedAt":1499268203235,"id":"AV0TWOIinKQtYP_yBYgG","_type":"case"}]

Each field is separated by the delimiter **},{**.

In regards to parsing out specific information from each case, I previously tried to just use the cut command. This mostly worked until I reached "metrics"; it doesn't always work for metrics because they will not always be listed in the same order.

I have asked my boss for help, and he told me this command might get me going in the right direction to adding only new hive cases to the survey, but I'm still very lost and want to avoid asking too much again.

```
curl -su user:pass http://myhiveIPaddress:9000/api/case | sed 's/},{/\n/g' | sed 's/\[{//g' | sed 's/}]//g' | awk -F '"caseId":' {'print $2'} | cut -f 1 -d , | sort -n | while read line; do echo '"caseId":'$line; done
```

Basically, I'm in *way* over my head and feel like I have no idea what I'm doing. If I need to clarify anything, or if it would help for me to post what I have so far in my API script, please let me know.

---

**Update**
Here is the potential logic for the script I'd like to write.

> get list of hive cases (curl ...)
>   read each field, delimited by },{
>   while read each field, check /tmp/addedHiveCases to see if caseId of field already exists
>   --> if it does not exist in file, add case to limesurvey and add caseId to /tmp/addedHiveCases
>   --> if it does exist, skip to next field

Comment: Added pseudocode for wanted script. If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

why are you thinking that the fields are separated by a "},{" delimiter?

The response of the `/api/case` API is a valid JSON format, that lists the cases.

Can you use a Python script to play with the API? If yes, I can help you write the script you need.

Comment: The base script I have written to add responses to limesurvey is in php, but I'll take any help I can get. What do you mean-- aren't they delimited by "},{"? The first field ends with _..."case"},_ and the second field starts with _{"createdBy":..._. Thanks for your response!

Comment: yes but the content is in JSON format: a list of key/value pairs separated by comma. You can use a JSON library to parse that response using PHP.

Comment: Note that there is a library called TheHive4py (python library) that helps playing with TheHive APIs

Comment: So by researching parsing json using php like you mentioned, I found the php command json_decode. It definitely helps to clean up the response and make it easier to read, but I'm still unsure where to go from here. If possible I would like to stick to php instead of python since my api to add responses is in php. How can I help you help me?

Comment: If you can parse the JSON, then you can get the `caseId` field and check if it has been imported in your `/tmp/addedHiveCases` file etc...